# implement a "reset"-gesture for a kinect controlled application

Tags: actionscript-3, air, kinect

i am working on an application ( game sorta ) which uses the kinect as an input device.
i need a "moderator" to be able to reset the application once new users are interested.

i was thinking that covering the sensor with a hand for some seconds could do the trick.
however the only way to achieve that would be to analyze the rgb camera output all the time for "all black".

any thoughts on this?

thanks a lot.

p.s.: i am using the openni sdk on mac and the game is developed in as3 using the airkinect framework.

Answer (score 1):

What you mentioned sounds like a fair solution. On similar lines you could even use the depth sensor and detect the depth as (approx) 0 to trigger the reset.

However, I can come up with cases where using either one solution may be a false positive. Keeping it simple for the user, you might even want to use a combination of zero depth and all black for this.

Making it complex and accurate you could use a QR code or a RED Paper to indicate (STOP). A GREEN (for GO), etc.

(Kindly mark this solution as accepted if you find it sufficient. Awaiting your comments, if any.)

Comment: To avoid false positives, you could add a timer, as well. Make it so that the depth needs to be 0 for a half second or something in order to trigger the reset. That would avoid any accidental movements close to the camera (mobile scrolling works in a similar manner for detecting accidental touches and actual click throughs)

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be using voice recognition instead. It seems like a more natural interaction than covering the sensor. If you keep the voice commands limited it works very well.

I've used voice recognition in the past to determine the leftmost and rightmost edge of a "playfield" by holding my hand on one of the edges and saying "calibrate",  "left", "right", and "Okay" to confirm. It worked very well. If you have a lot of people talking, you could listen for a keyphrase first. So "Kinect: calibrate" and "Kinect: left"  to filter out the false positives.

Answer (score 1):

You should first answer the question of how the user and moderator will be interacting with the application and the active interaction space.  If a moderator has to approach the Kinect sensor and cover up the camera in order to reset the instance, why not just give them a wireless keyboard or mouse to hold?  A mouse click or a keystroke can reset the scene in this case -- and a keyboard would offer many other keys to jump between multiple scenes, or configuration settings.

If you are truly needing a "hands free" solution for the moderator, I would look into gestures or speech recognition.  I'm not as familiar with OpenNI, so links below will reference Microsoft SDKs but can be used for reference and ideas...

In the case of speech recognition, an "activation" keyword can be used (e.g., "Kinect" or "Computer") followed by an action request (e.g., "Destruct sequence 3, code 1 B-2B-3", or just "reset" if you want to be boring).  You can read more about speech recognition using Microsoft libraries here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx

For gestures, you can use a static gesture to reset the scene -- for example, on the XBox holding one arm at your side and the other a 45-degree angle will send you back to the main menu.  You can always assume the moderator will be on a certain side, or will always be the second player to enter the scene.  You could just not care and let users reset the scene if need be.  You could also mix it up and have the moderator give a "control" gesture or voice command first, so the system knows they are the moderator, and then give the reset (or other) gesture.

Two gesture libraries that could help in this are here:

- http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/EvilClosetMonkey/Fizbin.Kinect.Gestures